# Creating enum with javassist

Tags: java, enums, javassist

I'm using javassist to create a class at runtime, based on a class schema (probably json). Some attributes of this class may be Enums, and I would like to know how to create a Enum field because CtClass doesn't seem appropriate to create it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its said that

> The new syntax introduced by J2SE 5.0 (including enums and generics) has not been supported.

in [the tutorial](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#limit)

Comment: but since enum is just a class implementing Enum, I think it's possible this way